# create a dictionary of with key as the attribute and value as model object

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Say i have this table:

```
class Blog(models.Model)
  title = models.CharField()
  body = models.CharField()
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

I need to create 3 rows with the title (title_1, title_2, title_3). I need to fetch all the blog objects and create a dictionary with key as the title and value as blog object.

```
blog_dict = {'title_1': <blog_object_1>, 'title_2': <blog_object_2>, 'title_2': <blog_object_3>}
```

I have 1 million records to work. Is there any efficient way to do it?

Comment: Why you need key as `title_1` e.t.c it seems unnecessary why not list of objects ? Can you be specific ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might do this task

```
blog_dict = {}
blogs = Blog.objects.all()
for blog in blogs:
    blog_dict[blog.title] = blog
```

as @ZXYNINE mentioned in the comment section below, it could be done with a single line instead of full form of for loop like so:

```
blog_dict  = { blog.title:blog for blog in blogs}
```

I find the first method is better for beginners, but also it worth to mention the other method as well.

Comment: Can we do it without using the for loop?

Comment: I don't think so, but maybe there is a way for that

Comment: I had to wait for my reputation to hit 50 before i could leave a comment, but you can skip the for loop by using a dict comprehension like so:
`blog_dict  = { blog.title:blog for blog in blogs}`

Comment: it is a for loop too but merged in a single line, but it will do the same process... I prefer to use the full form because he said in his question that he is very new to Python

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correct, you wish to create a dict that essentially maps names of each blog obj to the instance right? This will really come down to specific functions you use and how you create the dictionary. What i would do is create the dictionary WHILE you initalise each object instead of iterating overthem after they have been created, but that assumes you have access to the init function of the class and dont need the objects for anything else until this point. Im not quite sure what you mean by "`I need to create 3 rows`" in combination with "`I have 1 million records to work.`", so I cant give you an exact method to try. Lets assume what you meant was you wanted to divide your 1 million records into a table that is (1mil/3)columns by 3rows. I would do something like this:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    body = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

Blogs:'list[Blog]' = [Blog,]*1000000


BlogTable = []
BlogRowBuffer = {}
# Using an int to count instead of len(BlogRowBuffer) to save processing power
BlogRowCount = 0

for blog in Blogs:
    BlogRowBuffer[blog.title] = blog
    BlogRowCount +=1
    #Once you add the third item to the row buffer, the buffer is made into a column in the table.
    # And the values reset to start all over.
    if BlogRowCount == 3:
        BlogTable.append(BlogRowBuffer)
        BlogRowBuffer = {}
        BlogRowCount = 0
```

The problem is, no matter how you tackle it, you must iterate over 1million objects and that will always take a fair amount of time. You should use built-in python functions wherever possible as they are written in C and are generally far faster than anything else. You should also look into some python libraries which could help with this. I know that deque provides faster speeds when it comes to pop left/right but I dont know any off the top of my head that will speed this up.

Additionally, if you know the exact number of objects, you can pre-allocate space to a list before doing anything and then just modify the list by indexing which is faster than appending: see [this link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/faster-lists-in-python-4c4287502f0a). That link also shows that list comprehensions can be faster but I know from experence that you should always compare the times yourself as it depends on HOW you use the different methods.